# How to check if there is only one specific field who is updated with Firestore rules?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Application side, I have this code :

[image]

```
static func markTaskAsCompleted(field: String, task: Task) -> Promise<Bool> {
    return Promise<Bool> { seal in
        FirestoreHandler.shared.db.collection("tasks").document(task.id!).updateData([
            "\(field)": true
        ], completion: { (err) in
            seal.resolve(err != nil ? false : true, err)
        })
    }
}
```

I update a single field, `helper_completed` in this case. Here are the security rules :

```
match /tasks/{task_id} {
  ...
  allow update: if (...) || isValidTaskUpdate();
  ...
}

function isValidTaskUpdate() {
  return currentUser().uid == existingData().assigned.user_id &&
         incomingData().keys().size() == 1 &&
         'helper_completed' in incomingData();
}

function incomingData() {
  return request.resource.data;
}
```

The last check `'helper_completed' in incomingData()` always return false with the previous application code.

I have also tried :

```
 'helper_completed' in incomingData().keys();
  incomingData().hasAny('helper_completed');
```

So, how can I check if there is only one specific field updated in my update request ?

I have already checked :
[Firestore Security Rules - How can I check that a field is/isn't being modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176704/firestore-security-rules-how-can-i-check-that-a-field-is-isnt-being-modified?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check what fields are being updated, use [`request.writeFields`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#writeFields). In your case this should be:

```
"helper_completed" in request.writeFields && request.writeFields.size() == 1
```

Comment: This feature has been removed in favor of [new `Map` operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52192476/2805265)