# When are writeFields specified in Firestore requests and what replaces them?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The simulator [now displays an error message trying to access `request.writeFields`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52191901/6509751).
Before that `writeFields` in Firestore Security Rules did just not work in real requests.

The message states the following:

> The simulator only simulates client SDK calls; request.writeFields is always null for these simulations

Does this mean that `writeFields` are only specified in HTTP requests?

The [documentation only states this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#writeFields):

> writeFields: List of fields being written in a write request.

### A problem that arises from this

I am searching for something that replaces this property because it is **"always null"**.
`request.resource.data` in **`update`** also contains fields that *are not in the requests*, but already in the document to my knowledge.

#### Example

```
// Existing document:

  document:
    - name: "Peter"
    - age: 52
    - profession: "Baker"

// Update call:

  document:
    - age: 53

// request.resource.data in allow update contains the following:

  document:
    - name: "Peter"
    - age: 53
    - profession: "Baker"
```

But I only want `age`.

Comment: So you're saying that, in Firestore rules, you want to get a list of all the fields that a write request is attempting to modify?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes. I used to think that `writeFields` was about that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**EDIT Mar 4, 2020: `Map.diff()` replaces `writeFields` functionality**

The `Map.diff()` function gives the difference between two maps:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#diff

To use it in rules:

```
// Returns a MapDiff object
map1.diff(map2)
```

A `MapDiff` object has the following methods

```
addedKeys() // a set of strings of keys that are in after but not before
removedKeys() // a set of strings of keys that are in before but not after
changedKeys() // a set of strings of keys that are in both maps but have different values 
affectedKeys() // a set of strings that's the union of addedKeys() + removedKeys() + updatedKeys()
unchangedKeys() // a set of strings of keys that are in both maps and have the same value in both
```

For example:

```
// This rule only allows updates where "a" is the only field affected
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"])
```

---

**EDIT Oct 4, 2018: `writeFields` is no longer supported by Firestore and its functionality will eventually be removed.**

[writeFields](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#writeFields) is still valid, as you can see from the linked documentation.  What the error message in the simulator is telling you is that it's unable to simulate `writeFields`, as it only works with requests coming from client SDKs.  The simulator itself seems to be incapable of simulating requests exactly as required in order for writeFields to be tested.  So, if you write rules that use `writeFields`, you'll have to test them by using a client SDK to perform the read or write that would trigger the rule.

Comment: Are you saying that the stress in that error message is on "**simulates**"? I will need to do a lot more testing in that case because `writeFields` do not seem to be working for me as I described in my older question, which is linked at the beginning of this question.

Comment: Yes, if you want to validate your rules that work with writeFields, you'll need to do that with client code for now.

Comment: @DougStevenson the link to `writeFields` documentation doesn't mention anything about writeFields. Where can we find the docs for this?

Comment: @abagshaw writeFields was recently removed from the documentation, as it's being deprecated, and sometimes it doesn't work that way you'd expect.  As of now, you should work without it.

Comment: @DougStevenson is there some sort of workaround for issues like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671227/allow-update-on-single-field-in-firestore that relied on writeFields?

Comment: @DougStevenson Is there any alternative to writeFields then? Or planned..

Comment: I can answer my own question with this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/5NzKaYF4JYg
Long story short: Yes something is, by the sound of it, almost ready.

Comment: perfect answer!