# Send email to different email to verify registration using angular firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase-authentication

I was able to verify user email before registration. But I want to receive verification email to my email address to complete the registration process.
I want to get notification to my email address and after my approval only registration process completes.
I have check email verification:
**auth-service.ts**

```
 async SignIn(email,password)
    {
     const loading =await this.LoadingCtrl.create({
       message:'Authenticating..',
       spinner:"crescent",
       showBackdrop:true
     });
     loading.present();
     this.afauth.setPersistence(firebase.default.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
     .then(()=>{
       this.afauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
       .then((data)=>{
         if(!data.user.emailVerified){
           loading.dismiss();
           this.toast('Please check your credentials','warning');
           this.afauth.signOut();
         }else{
           loading.dismiss();
           this.router.navigate(['/home']);
         }
       })
       .catch(error=>{
         loading.dismiss();
         this.toast(error.message,'danger');
       })
     })
     .catch(error=>{
       loading.dismiss();
       this.toast(error.message,'danger');
     });
    }
```

to register:

```
async register(){
    if(this.firstname && this.lastname && this.email && this.password){
      const loading =await this.loadingCtrl.create({
        message:'Processing...',
        spinner:'crescent',
        showBackdrop:true
      });
      loading.present();
      
      this.afauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password)
      .then((data)=>{
        data.user.sendEmailVerification();
        this.afs.collection('user').doc(data.user.uid).set({
          'userId':data.user.uid,
          'userEmail':this.email,
          'userFirstname':this.firstname,
          'userLastname':this.lastname
        })
        .then(()=>{
          loading.dismiss();
          this.toast('Registration Success','success');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
          loading.dismiss();
          this.toast(error.message,'danger')
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to approve that users can use your app, which is different from allowing them to verify their own email address.

While this is a valid use-case, Firebase Authentication doesn't have built-in functionality for this use-case.

Firebase Authentication only deals with the *authentication* part, so allowing the user to provide their credentials - and verifying those credentials. To only allow users with a verified email address, or users that you've approved, to use the app is *authorization* and is part of the application logic you'll have to build yourself.

For allowing only approved users access to the app/data, the common process is:

1. Create a list of approved users in the database, or add a `isApproved` field to the profile document you already have that the users can't set themselves.
2. In your application code after authenticating the user, check if they are in the list of allowed users and only allow them to continue to the next screen in the app if they are.
3. If your database [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics) only allow users to read data if they are on the list of approved users.
4. In any custom backend code you have, check whether the user is approved before executing their request.

Comment: I have added `IsApproved:true` to user field. How do I change the database rule ? I tried doing `allow read, write:if request.auth.user.IsApproved!=false;` but it shows error.

Comment: That sounds like a new problem, so I recommend posting a new question if you can't figure it out after checking previous questions on the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bfirebase-security%5D+not+modify+field, such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143344/security-rules-to-allow-update-of-specific-fields/58144206#58144206

Comment: I have asked new question and here is the link for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545840/security-rules-to-allow-login-whose-field-isapproved-is-true