# Security rules to allow login whose field "IsApproved is true"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

While registring the account I have set default value as `false` for the field `IsApproved`. I want to write the security rules to allow login for those user whose `IsApproved:true` and route to `accessdenied` page whose `IsApproved:false`.
Code used for user registration

```
async register(){
    if(this.firstname && this.lastname && this.email && this.password){
      const loading =await this.loadingCtrl.create({
        message:'Processing...',
        spinner:'crescent',
        showBackdrop:true
      });
      loading.present();
      
      this.afauth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password)
      .then((data)=>{
        this.afs.collection('user').doc(data.user.uid).set({
          'userId':data.user.uid,
          'IsApproved':false,
          'userEmail':this.email,
          'userFirstname':this.firstname,
          'userLastname':this.lastname
        })
        .then(()=>{
          loading.dismiss();
          this.toast('Registration Success','success');
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        })
        .catch(error=>{
          loading.dismiss();
          this.toast(error.message,'danger')
        })
      })
    }
  }
```

How do I check if `IsApproved` field is `true` or `false` while user try to `sign in`
code used for signIn

```
async SignIn(email,password)
    {
     const loading =await this.LoadingCtrl.create({
       message:'Authenticating..',
       spinner:"crescent",
       showBackdrop:true
     });
     loading.present();
     this.afauth.setPersistence(firebase.default.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
     .then(()=>{
       this.afauth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
       .then((data)=>{
         if(!data.user){
           loading.dismiss();
           this.toast('Please check your credentials','warning');
           this.afauth.signOut();
         }else{
           loading.dismiss();
           this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
         }
       })
       .catch(error=>{
         loading.dismiss();
         this.toast(error.message,'danger');
       })
     })
     .catch(error=>{
       loading.dismiss();
       this.toast(error.message,'danger');
     });
    }
```

I tried checking using If else  `If(!data.user.IsApproved)`

```
  if(!data.user){
       loading.dismiss();
       this.toast('Please check your credentials','warning');
       this.afauth.signOut();
     }else{
       loading.dismiss();
        if(data.user.IsApproved===true){
          this.router.navigate(['/menu']);
         }else{
            this.router.navigate(['/accessdenied']);
      }
       
    }
   })
```

but when I try It says `Property 'IsApproved' does not exist on type 'User'.`
My model looks like

```
export interface User {
    userId:string;
    IsApproved:boolean;
    userEmail:string;
    userPhoto:string;
    userFirstname:string;
    userLastname:string;
}
```

I tried to change the security rules
`allow read,write:if request.auth.uid.IsApproved!=false;`  It says `unknown error occurred`
I am trying to allow only those user whose `IsApproved` field is `true` to access my app for other I am trying to route to access denied.

Comment: Can you show the snippet of code where you did `if(!data.user.IsApproved)`? The only place where I see you use `data` right now is in the completion of `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `data` there is a `UserCredential` object, which you can't add your own properties to.

Comment: I have updated my code.  Yes I have used with `signInWithEmailAndPassword`. If I cannot use there then where should I check ? After complition of Sign In we get user detail right ? so why we cannot check there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the `IsApproved` value in a user-specific profile document in Firestore, you can [`get()` that document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore#.get) in your security rules and use the value from it.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user/$(request.auth.uid)).data.IsApproved == true;
  }
}
```

For another example of this, I recommend checking out the Firebase documentation on [attribute and role based access control](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#attribute-based_and_role-based_access) from where I copied and modified the example above.

Comment: And How do I redirect to access denied page if the user is not approved ?

Comment: I recommend focussing your questions better going forward, as I intentionally focussed my answer on the problem you have in the title: "Security rules to allow login whose field "IsApproved is true"".  ---- To handle the client-side of this in your application, you'll need to [read the user's document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data), get the `IsApproved` value from there, and handle routing based on that.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It was new for me that we can use `get()` to update the security rules.

Comment: I recommend spending some time reading the documentation I linked, as there are many features in there that will be helpful going forward.

Comment: For sure I will go over the documentation.