# Firestore model and security room for multiusers "open" chat app

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'am creating a chat app with the following requirements. Each chat is related to an event in real life.

- anyone can join/leave a chat which are multi-users chats (provided he knows the chat Id)
- anyone can post messages after joining
- anyone can indicate if he is attending/waiting/rejecting the related event =>`attendance`
- User can only **list** chats they have an attendance to.

The idea is: if someone gave me the ID of a chat I can join him and afterwards it will be in my list but I cannot list all chats

**Option 1**
This solution seems a bit dirty but the model would be (not all fields)

```
- /chat(collection)
--- creator_id
--- members [Array of userId]
--- attendance [Array of user attendances Objects]
- /messages (sub collection)
--- sender_id
```

Rules:

```js
match /chat/{chatId} {
     allow create : request.resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid;
     allow read : if request.auth != null
     allow list : if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members
     allow update : editingOnlyAllowedFields(["members", "attendance"]) && isCreatorOrMember(chatId);
     
     match /messages/{messageId} {

         // Use same as chat for get/list
         allow create : request.resource.data.sender_id == request.auth.uid;
         allow update : resource.data.sender_id == request.auth.uid;
}
}

function editingOnlyAllowedFields(allowedFields) {
    let editedKeys = request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys();
    return editedKeys.hasOnly(allowedFields);
}
// Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140909/3979236

function isCreatorOrMember(chatId) {
  return resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}
```

This makes it easy front side to get chats the user is member of (userId in-array members) but this also allows anyone to remove users or change attendance which is problematic.

**Option 2**
Model:

```
- /chat(collection)
--- creator_id
--- /attendance (sub collection)
----- userId (== document Id)
----- status
--- /messages (sub collection)
----- sender_id
```

Rules:

```js
function isChatMember(chatId) {
    return request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(chatId)/attendance/$(request.auth.uid)) 
}

match /chat/{chatId} {
    allow get if request.auth != null
    allow list if isChatMember(chatId) // But this makes a Read on the subcollection. Another option is to have a Cloud Function creating an array member on chat when /attendance/userId is created
    allow write if request.resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid

    match /attendance/{userId} {
        allow write if userId == request.auth.uid
        // Use same as chat for get/list

    match /messages/{messageId} {

         // Use same as chat for get/list
         allow create : request.resource.data.sender_id == request.auth.uid;
         allow update : resource.data.sender_id == request.auth.uid;
}}
```

This solution seems to works but "Rules are not filters" and I think we cannot from the front app make a request to get chats for which `attendance.userId exists`. Said otherwise we cannot use a where filter on a subcollection.

Solution 1? : Cloud Function to maintain the array of member directly on the chat object
Solution 2? : compound query on attendance to get the chatIds, then request with the IDs (but there might be a lot).

Answer (score 0):

try the following

if i am getting you correctly you don't want unauthorized modifications to the members and attendance fields.

```
match /chat/{chatId} {
  allow create: request.resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid;
  allow read: if request.auth != null;
  allow list: if request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
  allow update: editingOnlyAllowedFields(["members", "attendance"]) && isCreatorOrMember(chatId);
  
  match /messages/{messageId} {
    allow create: request.resource.data.sender_id == request.auth.uid;
    allow update: resource.data.sender_id == request.auth.uid;
  }
}

function editingOnlyAllowedFields(allowedFields) {
  let editedKeys = request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys();
  return editedKeys.hasOnly(allowedFields);
}

function isCreatorOrMember(chatId) {
  return resource.data.creator_id == request.auth.uid || request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Indeed I forgot the isChatMember part in my solution 1 but with this, any member can edit the `members` and `attendance` arrays and remove/change attendance for anyone in the chat; if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

I finally came up with 2 solutions that meed my requirements. None is perfect and here are the pro and cons.

## Solution 1

### Description

- Store an array of members ids on the chat
- Store an array of member attendance details (Map with key = userId) on the chat
- Complex rules to allow user to update only their info

### Pro

- No attached Cloud Function to denormalize
- Fewer Read / write cost

### Cons

- Harder to read, maintain

### Rules

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /moods/{moodId} {
      allow get: if isAuthenticated();
      allow create: if request.auth.uid ==  request.resource.data.creator_id;
      allow update: if (isAdmin() || isCreator()
                      || (editedOwnMembership() && editingOnlyAllowedFields(["members"]))
                      || (editedOwnAttendance() && editingOnlyAllowedFields(["attendance"])))
                    && request.resource.data.creator_id == resource.data.creator_id;
      allow delete: if isCreator();
      allow list: if (isMember() || isCreator());

    }
    
  }


function isAuthenticated() {
  return request.auth.uid != null;
}
function isCreator() {
  return request.auth.uid == resource.data.creator_id; 
}
function isAdmin() {
  return request.auth.uid in resource.data.admins;
}
function isMember() {
  return request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
}

function editedOwnMembership() {
  return 
  (resource.data.members.toSet().difference(request.resource.data.members.toSet()) == [request.auth.uid].toSet())//Deletion
  || (request.resource.data.members.toSet().difference(resource.data.members.toSet()) == [request.auth.uid].toSet()) // Addition
  
}
function editedOwnAttendance() {
  let edit = request.resource.data.attendance.diff(resource.data.attendance).affectedKeys();
  return edit.hasAny([request.auth.uid]); // UserId must be in the edited
  }
function editingOnlyAllowedFields(allowedFields) {
  let editedKeys = request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys();
  return editedKeys.hasOnly(allowedFields);
}

}
```

## Solution 2

### Description

- Have an attendance subcollection
- Have a Cloud Function to maintain an array of members on chat (necessary to cope with the `list` rule and be able to list my chats)

### Pros

- Cleaner model, easier to read

### Cons

- More Read requests due to `isParentChatAdmin()` fetching data from another collection
- More Write request as writing in `attendance` results in a write in `chats` too through Cloud Functions

### Rules

```js
    rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /moods/{moodId} {
          allow get: if isAuthenticated();
          allow create: if request.auth.uid ==  request.resource.data.creator_id;
          allow update: if (isAdmin() || isCreator())
                        && request.resource.data.creator_id == resource.data.creator_id;
          allow delete: if isCreator();
          allow list: if (isMember() || isCreator());
    
          match /user_attendance/{userId} {
            // Consider the chat Id is needed to be able to list, sufficient security
            // Maybe be careful if compound is activated on attendance
            allow read: if request.auth != null;
            // Allow anyone to attend
            allow create: if (request.auth != null && request.auth.uid = userId) 
                          || isParentChatAdmin()
            // Allow edit only yours or admin of parent chat
            allow update: if request.auth.uid ==  userId || isParentChatAdmin(moodId);
            allow delete: if request.auth.uid ==  userId || isParentChatAdmin(moodId);
          }
        }
        
      }
    
    
    function isAuthenticated() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    function isCreator() {
      return request.auth.uid == resource.data.creator_id; 
    }
    function isAdmin() {
      return request.auth.uid in resource.data.admins;
    }
    function isMember() {
      return request.auth.uid in resource.data.members;
    }
    
    function isParentChatAdmin(chatId) {
      // Creates a READ request
      return request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/chats/$(moodId)).data.admins;
    }
    
    }
```