# Does FieldValue.serverTimestamp() add additional data?

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function

```
  Future<void> _updateDocument(String path, {Map<String, dynamic> data}) async {
    final Map<String, dynamic> stampedData = {'updatedAt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()};
    if (data != null) stampedData.addAll(data);
    try {
      print('Updating document : $path with $stampedData');
      final DocumentReference documentReference = _fireStore.document(path);
      await documentReference.updateData(stampedData);
    } on PlatformException catch (error) {
      throw UserFriendlyException('Operation Failed', error.message);
    }
  }
```

Which updates a certain document. But I keep getting the following error

> Write failed at groups/YUUjiGgQ6De4IMshWmRF: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Because I have the following rule

```
incomingData().keys().hasOnly(['updatedAt', 'displayName']) == true
```

So I tested how many keys there actually are and it turns out there are 5 keys

```
function isValidGroupRename(){
    return incomingData().keys().hasAll(['updatedAt', 'displayName']) == true &&
             incomingData().keys().size() < 6
}
```

Because this functions passes the test but `< 5` does not. When I look at the data object right before the I call the update, so this line `print('Updating document : $path with $stampedData');` it tells me that I only update 2 values

```
Updating document : groups/YUUjiGgQ6De4IMshWmRF with {updatedAt: FieldValue(Instance of 'MethodChannelFieldValue'), displayName: jjjjjgi}
```

So does FieldValue.serverTimestamp() add on fields? And if so what are those fields so I can check for them.

Comment: By the time it hits your security rules, `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` has been converted into a normal `Date and time` value. No extra data is written.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there any way I could debug why there are 5 keys instead of 2 / what those keys are

Comment: I have no idea what `incomingData()` is in your rules. A common mistake however is expecting that `request.resource` only contains the data that is written from the client. It actually contains the data as it will exist after the operation completes (if successful). So if there are 5 fields in the doc, and you're updating 2 of them: `request.resource` will contain 5 fields, 2 of which are updated.

Comment: Aah yes that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time it hits your security rules, `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` has been converted into a normal Date and time value. No extra data is written.

A common mistake however is expecting that `request.resource` only contains the data that is written from the client. It actually contains the data as it will exist after the operation completes (if successful).

So if there are 5 fields in the doc, and you're updating 2 of them: `request.resource` will contain 5 fields, 2 of which are updated.

Also see:

- [Number of update fields in firestore security rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326722/number-of-update-fields-in-firestore-security-rules)
- [Allow update on single field in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671227/allow-update-on-single-field-in-firestore)