# Firebase: How to prevent writing a specific field in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

The ruleset protects the user's entry like follows:

- only him or an admin can read his data
- only an admin can update a user's permissions
- a user can update all his data, unless he sets the permissions object

The rule looks like:

```
match /users/{userId} {
  allow read: if isCurrentUser(userId) || isAdmin();
  allow write: if (isCurrentUser(userId) && !isModifyingPermissions()) || isAdmin();

  function isModifyingPermissions(){
    return request.resource.data['permissions'] != null;
  }
}
```

I'm stuck with the `isModifiyingPermissions()` function. It properly refuses a write in case the request has a value for the `permissions` property. However, the rule crashes if no `permissions` property is provided, stating the following:

```
Error: simulator.rules line [19], column [15]. Property permissions is undefined on object.
```

How can one write "check presence of a property on request resource" ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, here's the solution:

```
  function isModifyingPermissions(){
    return request.resource.data.keys().hasAny(["permissions"]);
  }
```

Comment: note to self: search some more before asking the question :-) The following helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176704/firestore-security-rules-how-can-i-check-that-a-field-is-isnt-being-modified?rq=1